# Programiticaly Multiple Columns in Tableview ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to create a table with multiple columns, I am using array of cells.
Following is my code, I get single columns every time.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";  

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

   cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] ;     

    CGFloat x = 0.0f;
    UIView *lastCol = [[cell columnCells] lastObject];
    if (lastCol) x = lastCol.frame.origin.x + lastCol.frame.size.width;

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {

         UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, i, 40.0f)] ;
        UIView *gridCell = l;

        CGRect f = gridCell.frame;
        f.origin.x += x;
        gridCell.frame = f;

        [cell.contentView addSubview:gridCell];

        CGFloat colWidth = [self widthForColumn:i];

        x += colWidth + 1.0f;
        [[cell columnCells] addObject:gridCell];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {       
        UILabel *l = (UILabel*)[cell columnCells][i];
       l.text =self.department[indexPath.row];     
       }  

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: your problem is at line `UILabel *l = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, i, 40.0f)`. your all label are at same place... 0.0, 0.0. is main problme

Comment: How should I correct this?

Comment: you want to divide one cell in 3 columns... right?

Comment: Yes, somewhat like that, then after that onclick of cell I want that label text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
// table view delegates
- (int)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (int) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 100;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    double boxWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/3;

    for (int i=0;i<=2;i++) {
        UIView *mView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(boxWidth*i, 0, boxWidth, 100)];
        if (i==0) {
            mView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        } else if (i==1) {
            mView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
        } else if (i==2) {
            mView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        }

        [cell addSubview:mView];
    }


    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: What if, if I want to add labels in all the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Fahim, I just modified his code and got what I wanted.

Here's the exact requirement which I was looking for.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];

    double boxWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/3;

    for (int i=0;i<=2;i++) {

        UIView *mView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(boxWidth*i, 0, boxWidth, 100)];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 250, 15)];
        [label setText:self.department[indexPath.row]];

        [cell addSubview:mView];
        [mView addSubview:label];

    }


    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;

}
```